# Send a String from Android to a Spring server

Tags: java, android, spring-mvc, heroku, httpurlconnection

I am trying to send an String from my android app to the server. The String contains: username, password and a image encoded in base 64. Between them is a space(" "). I am using heroku to store the server and I use a postgreSQL database. I have a table named `users` with the columns : `userid,password, encoded image`, all of them in format text.

When I create a new user I give the `userid and the password`, the column encodedimage is empty. I want to make an update to the table when I want to upload the image to the server and edit the `encodedimage` column.

Here is how I send the String from android:

```
request=Utils.name+" "+Utils.password;
            ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, byteArrayOutputStream);
            request = request+ " " + Base64.encodeToString(byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray(), Base64.DEFAULT);
try {
        URL url = new URL(params[0]);
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        urlConnection.setReadTimeout(15000);
        urlConnection.setConnectTimeout(15000);
        urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
        urlConnection.setChunkedStreamingMode(0);

        OutputStream outputStream = urlConnection.getOutputStream();
        OutputStreamWriter outputStreamWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, "UTF-8");
        BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(outputStreamWriter);
        bufferedWriter.write(request);

        bufferedWriter.flush();
        bufferedWriter.close();
        outputStreamWriter.close();
        outputStream.close();

        int response=urlConnection.getResponseCode();
        urlConnection.disconnect();
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

If I update my table from `cmd` it works but from code it doesn't.

Here is my controller:

```
@Controller
public class UploadController implements Constant {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/upload-image", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public void handleUploadImageRequest(@RequestBody String request) {
        String[] details = request.split(" ");
        String name = details[0];
        String password = details[1];
        byte[] decodedImage = Base64.getDecoder().decode(details[2]);
        if (decodedImage.length > 0) {
            try {
                Image image = ImageIO.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(decodedImage));
                Connection connection = null;
                Statement statement = null;
                String updateUSER = "UPDATE " + TABLE_USERS + " SET " + COLUMN_ENCODEDIMAGE + "='" + details[2]
                        + "' WHERE " + COLUMN_USERID + "='" + name + "' AND '" + COLUMN_PASSWORD + "='" + password + "';";
                try {
                    connection = DatabaseUtils.getConnection();
                    statement = connection.createStatement();
                    statement.executeUpdate(updateUSER);
                    statement.close();
                    connection.close();
                } catch (SQLException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In heroku logs I found:

> org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: Required request body is missing: public void com.rares.controllers.UploadController.handleUploadImageRequest(java.lang.String)

Is the android code ok? Where is the problem or how should I do it. Please don't point me to deprecated methods.
I

Answer (score 0):

Wrong posting. Your request should more look like:

```
request = "username=" + userName
         + "&password=" + passWord
         + "&image=" + base64String.
```

And then the values should be url encoded yet.

Comment: But i know how to obtain the values in the controller with split(" ")

Comment: Can you edit my controller with your method please? Should I do it with request params? Why request body is not usefull now?

Comment: You will not send spaces anymore as you can see. So no splitting on spaces either.

Comment: But I don t understand why I should sent the values like you said from Android. Can you explain?

Comment: Well thats a way it can be done if you send key=value pairs. If you do a POST.

Comment: No. I will not do that. Posting some parameter values is pretty basic stuff. I wonder why you did not find some Spring examples. There must be plenty on the internet. By the way: why are you calling that a java server? Its a Spring server insnt it?